# Define a constant function call

Tags: php, constants

My code is like this:

```
<?php
define("ERROR", "SOMETHING WRONG WITH MY DATABASE");
... 
if (!mysql_query($q)){
  die(ERROR);
}
?>
```

Now I want to replace  "SOMETHING WRONG WITH MY DATABASE" with `mysql_error()` in case I want to debug it. what is the easiest way ?

This does not seem to work work: `define("ERROR", mysql_error());`

---- edit ---

I don't want to use mysql_error() under production environment, it may help the attacker figure out something related to my database? That's my point of using a constant string

as in **C** you can do
`#define x yourfunction()`
I'm not sure if I can do the same in php

Comment: What's wrong with just using a function?

Comment: @Juhana I added my explanation..

Comment: `function my_error() { return mysql_error() }` - when you go live replace `mysql_error()` with a string. There's no reason to try to make a function "constant", whatever that means.

Comment: ok.. maybe that's the only way to go

Comment: Why not turn it to a global variable instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is "you cannot do that".  The whole point of **constant** is that it's **constant** as in **its value is never changed**.  If it refers to a function call, the function can return any value - and it's not constant any more.

One trick you can do is define the function call itself to be the value of the constant - and then `eval` it on demand, something like this:

```
define("ERROR", "return mysql_error()");
...
die(eval(ERROR));
```

However this is really a rather bad code.  You'd be much better off doing

```
die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Your horrible, horrible `eval()` would require the constant to be defined with a value of `return mysql_error();` or it won't output anything. But why on earth anyone would do that is beyond me.

Comment: Or prepending the static string to the error message, as @DaveRandom suggests.

Comment: is mysql_error() unsafe in a production environment ? I don't want to display the mysql error so the attacker can get something out of it... that's my point of using a constant string.

Comment: @iKid what I do is something like this: Have a global var boolean called `$__DEVMODE`, which is true in dev and false in production. Then have a function like this: `function mysql_safe_error ($link = NULL) { return ($GLOBALS['__DEVMODE']) ? mysql_error($link) : mysql_errno($link); }`. Then your code would be `if (!mysql_query($q)) { die(mysql_safe_error()); }`

Comment: @DaveRandom yes, agree, my mistake, I updated that.  In any event, it's a rather bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

A constant should be exactly what the name implies - **constant**. You cannot redeclare a constant, and anything that has a *variable* value should be stored in - you guessed it - a *variable*.

However, you could do something like this:

```
<?php

  define("ERROR", "SOMETHING WRONG WITH MY DATABASE: ");

  // ... 

  if (!mysql_query($q)){
    die(ERROR . mysql_error());
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql_error() has to be called AFTER the sql operation that you are trying to catch.  You cannot catch this error with a predeclared constant or variable.  You either have to call it directly, or call another function which calls it, like so:

```
die(mysql_error());
```

or:

```
define("ERROR", "Database Problem ");

function Err() {
  $sql_err = ERROR . mysql_error();
  return $sql_err;
}
// sql operation here, then test for error
die(Err());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like Stefan suggested and add a DEBUG constant which you can switch between prod and dev environment:

```
define('DEBUG', 1);

// In the function:
// ...
echo ERROR;

if (DEBUG){
  echo mysql_error();   
}

die();
```