# How to call a constant as a function name?

Tags: php, function, constants

In PHP, you can call functions by calling their name inside a variable.

```php
function myfunc(){ echo 'works'; }

$func = 'myfunc';
$func(); // Prints "works"
```

But, you can't do this with constants.

```php
define('func', 'myfunc');

func(); // Error: function "func" not defined
```

There are workarounds, like these:

```php
$f = func;
$f(); // Prints "works"

call_user_func(func); // Prints "works"

function call($f){ $f(); }
call(func); // Prints "works"
```

The PHP documentation on [**`callable`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) says:

> A PHP function is passed by its name as a string. Any built-in or user-defined function can be used, except language constructs.

There seems to be nothing about constant values not being callable.

I also tried to check it, and of course,

```php
var_dump(is_callable(func));
```

prints `bool(true)`.

Now, is there an explanation as to why is it this way? As far as I can see all the workarounds rely on assigning the constant value to a variable, by why can't constant be called?

**And again, just to make it super clear, I don't need a way to call the function, I even presented some there. I want to know *why* PHP doesn't allow calling the function directly through the constant.**

Comment: Maybe this clears up something: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925176/php-define-a-constant-function-call

Comment: @RichardA Yes, I read that question, but compared to that question my question is why doesn't defining `func` to `"mysql_error"` and calling `func()` work.

Comment: I guess that's just how PHP works. When you do `func()`, PHP expects a function called func, despite func being a callable. The best answer I'm be able to give you is "You can't call a constant as a function without the workaround.".

Comment: `php > function myfunc(){ echo 'works'; }
    php > define('func_constant', 'return myfunc();');
    php > echo func_constant;
    return myfunc();
    php > eval(func_constant);
    works`

Comment: @Fivell I know that is another workaround, but I want to know why PHP does this.

Comment: @Fivell `eval` is evil.

Comment: @Pietu1998 Tbh, as AngularAddict stated in my answer, you should ask the PHP devs.

Comment: @RichardA Sure, I just couldn't find a quick way :D

Comment: @Pietu1998, because PHP supports the concept of variable functions. (but not constant functions). Nothing more. It just doesn't support this http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Comment: @RichardA Well, at least there it says exactly "if a **variable** name has parentheses appended to it". This is enough for me; change your answer to that and I'll accept it since you found it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for the why/reason I guess the only answer (which will probably not satisfy you) is:
Because it hasn't been proposed, discussed and accepted on https://wiki.php.net/rfc .

Comment: Yes, so there is no real reason for not allowing that; it could be proposed, accepted and added to PHP? @RichardA actually found a piece of documentation that at least confirms that variable functions only work with variables. http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Comment: I guess it's technically possible. When the runtime detects that there is no such function it _could_ in the next step try to find a constant with that name and start over. Maybe somewhere around http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=Zend/zend_vm_def.h;h=7b377dcf2c87d02998cfcdafff6bf34af765cc8c;hb=HEAD#l2629 But whether that's a good feature is another question. Honestly, what does it bring to the table that outweights the possible confusion?

Answer (score 4):

This works since PHP 7.0. But you have to use the more verbose syntax, so that PHP knows you want to execute `myfunc` instead of `func`.

```
<?php
function myfunc(){ echo 'works'; }
define('func', 'myfunc');

(func)();
```

Try this online: https://3v4l.org/fsGmo

The problem with PHP is that constants and identifiers are expressed as the same thing in the tokenizer. [See online how this syntax is tokenized by PHP](https://3v4l.org/uE4kg)

When you use parentheses to change precedence of operations on the constant, you tell PHP to first parse the constant and use its value to execute the function. Otherwise PHP will think that `func` is the name of your function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. Works for me.

```
constant('func')();
```

`constant()` function returns value of the constant, in your case its `myfunc`, then apply round brackets `()` and you will have valid `myfunc()` call.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to call a constant as a function, like so:

```
define('FUNC', 'myFunction');

function myFunction()
{
    echo 'Oh, hello there.';
}

FUNC(); // Fatal error: Call to undefined function FUNC()
```

Will cause the PHP Interpreter to expect a function called FUNC. Hence the error ***Fatal error:** Call to undefined function FUNC()*

Despite the type of the constant FUNC being `callable`, calling it as a function won't work. Simply because PHP expects a function named FUNC.

So without a workaround, you won't be able to call a function directly through a constant.

Comment: Yes, this is something, but I told most of this in the question. I'm still looking for some explanation for why they made it like that, if there is any.

Comment: And why are you asking this from users in here and not from PHP developers itself?

Comment: @Pietu1998 I think there is no explanation for it. It just is what it is I guess. It would be a bit confusing if constant would be callable like that wouldn't it?

Comment: True, people wouldn't know if that was a constant or a function, but still.